# Binding image control source inside dll from web app in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, dll, embedded-resource

I have a C# library where i have one img html control.I am using that library inside my web application.
Now, I want to bind that image src from my web app. img src path can be any shared path over network OR inside my web app.
Also, i tried to set put  css class name , that css classname is in my web app and css className image url is in my web app image path.
How to set img source path from my web app...please help me...i m stuck so badly...

Code inside C# DLL:

```
<div src="//IP address/BC/Custom/SSPTZ/Images/Search/info/"></div>
```

In my web App, when this dll is getting loaded. this img tag is loading but its not binding to that image path...

its coming like this: